# Adding new elements from a form to a collection in Meteor

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

So I have this use case:

I have a list of contacts on a page, and want to allow the user to add new ones to the list.
In order to add a contact, there is a form with two inputs which can be filled out and there is a button to send out the form.

This is pretty straight forward in Meteor. I bind the submit event to the form as in this snippet:

```
Template.contacts.events
  'submit #new_contact': (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()

    firstName = $('#first_name').val()
    lastName = $('#last_name').val()

    Contacts.insert(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)
    $('#new_contact input').val('') # Clear the inputs
```

So well, this is also pretty easy, but I don't like the idea of referencing specific ids in the form, getting them with JQuery and then inserting a new contact to the list. I also think this has to scale very badly, if the form had 20 fields, I'd have to search for 20 elements in the form, which doesn't seem very clean.

I'd like to know if there is a better way around this problem, like binding the form inputs to an object / collection so that it gets updated automatically when the user introduces data in the form and then only persisting it when the form gets submitted.

Answer (score 1):

There is automatic support for this planned (I think), but in the meantime, you can probably get around most of your objections by using the template object:

```
Template.contact.events
  'submit form.contact': (event, template) ->
     firstName = template.find('input[name=first_name]').value
```

Alternatively, in the body of a event helper, `this.currentTarget` is the form itself.